# How to get the DataTemplate's content from an ItemsControl?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have an `ItemsControl`. That `ItemsControl` has a context menu. My requirement is to get the content of the `DataTemplate` on menu item's  click. I want to delete the data template item. My sample code is as below:

```
<ItemsControl>    
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="listItem">
            <MenuItem
                Command="{Binding DataContext.ListRemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                Header="Delete Panel" />                      
         </ContextMenu>
     </ItemsControl.Resources>    
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>                              
             <StackPanel Background="White">
                 <Label Content="{Binding MyLabelContent}" />                                                  
             </StackPanel>                           
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemControl>
```

My current `CommandParameter` passes the `ContentPresenter`. By using the content presenter I get the `DataTemplate`. I have also tried `DataTemplate.FindName()`, But that is also not working. Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Why do you want to manipulate the `DataTemplate`? I guess it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe what are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: @dymanoid, Thanks for your reply, I want to drop the list content inside the data template. At the runtime I want to delete the item by using the context menu. Before I have set the context menu stackpanel(indise the datatemplate). But menuitem command is not fired in viewmodel because it datacontext is set as model. So I have change the context menu to Itemcontrol resources. Now I want to delete the content of the datatemplate at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don't manipulate the `DataTemplate`, but you manipulate the data in `DataContext`(aka VM).
Since you are using `ItemsControl`, you won't have `SelectedItem` Property ready to know which one is selected. Therefore you need to bind the `ContextMenu` inside the `DataTemplate`.

```
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Background="White">
             <Label Content="{Binding MyLabelContent}">
                 <Label.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                       <MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.ListRemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl, AncestorLevel=3}}"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding MyLabelContent}"
                                 Header="Delete Panel" />                      
                    </ContextMenu>
                 </Label.ContextMenu>
             </Label>
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
```

Notice:

- `Command`'s `RelativeSource` `AncestorLevel` grows up by 1
- `CommandParameter` binds to LabelContent

Then, you need to delete the `ItemsControl.Resources` content.

Comment: By using the above code it will shows the binding error in the output window. Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='3''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ListRemoveCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand'). It is not hitting the command in viewmodel.

Comment: I do not know exactly your Command is located, so sorry but you should figure the AncestorLevel out yourself. If I were you, I would specify specific location (using static) or remove the AncestorLevel and let it find it for you instead.

Comment: My command is located in viewmodel class. Without specifying the AncestorLevel it will search the ListRemoveCommand in Model class. But ListRemoveCommand is located in viewmodel class. I have also tried like this, <MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.ListRemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:ViewModelClass}}}" Header="Delete Panel" /> But it also not hitting the command event in viewmodel.